# Phonegap blackberry file system root

Tags: cordova, blackberry, filesystems

In a phonegap app when using:

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 8*1024, function (storage) { console.log(storage.root); });
```

I get the root folder as:

```
file:///accounts/1000/appdata/MyApp.testDev_MyApp___6f30ae7d/data/webviews/webfs/persistent/local__0/
```

I'd like to be able to access the top most directory. I believe this is suppose to be the data directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think [the bb documentation on the file plugin](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/cordova_file_file.md.html) is a good place to start, which also mentioned [the awesome html5 rocks tutorial.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

To answer your question, no, the data directory is not 'the top most directory,' it is the `data/webviews/webfs/persistent/local__0` directory, exactly like the one you referenced in your post.

Using the file system api plugin, there are a number of directories you can use depending on your specific needs.  If by 'top most directory' you mean the application directory (ie: `file:///accounts/1000/appdata/<app id>/`) then you are probably looking for `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory`.  That being said, this is **not** a writable directory.

Again, please check out that documentation link.  There is a table there outlining each of the different options you have at your disposal, including which you are able to read/ write from